# Phonegap/Cordova how to open a native file open dialog for android?

Tags: android, cordova

I write an android application based on Cordova and JQuery Mobile. I have to open a picture from SD card of the device. The user has to pick it.

Is there a way to use a file open dialog in android from HTML based applications? The application is a port from blackberry (WebWorks). On this system I had to write my own extension. I don't think Cordova brings us this fileopendialog. But maybe there is a solution to create a plugin like in webworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a Image from the image library:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

This works directly with android. If it is a file from Filesystem:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File
But this will not create a Fileseletion Dialog. This hast to be implemented within the javascript.